# i have some problem about current time in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl

I am the first student to start vhdl recently. It is currently working on the FPGA board.
I wish my seven-segment would have the current time whenever I pressed the RESET button. Is there a way to solve it?

I searched stackoverflow all day. but i can not find solution..

```
  -- Time information
  constant HOUR_INT   : integer                       := 00;  --  I think we should put the current time in here.
  constant HOUR_HEX   : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)  := X"00";
  constant MINUTE_INT : integer                       := 00;
  constant MINUTE_HEX : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)  := X"00";
```

```
if reset = '0' then
      hour <= conv_std_logic_vector(datetime.hour_int, 5)
```

in this code proportion, why i have to input 5 next to hout_int?

Comment: It's depending on what you call the current time.
You can create a time counter but you have to initialize the time with something. I need more informations on your system to help you. Does your FPGA have an internet connection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it isn't possible to get the current time of the system (considering the attempts / questions of other people on this forum). So it's also impossible to use reset for get the current time.

Maybe it's usefull to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355021/time-stamp-in-vhdl)

someone who has already tried it in a different way with an RTC (with success):
- [here](http://jimmy-embedded-c-n-vhdl.blogspot.com/2010/09/synthesizable-rtc-in-vhdl-coming-soon.html) non-manually set clock
- [here](http://jimmy-embedded-c-n-vhdl.blogspot.com/2011/01/rtc-on-fpga-with-manual-set.html) manually set clock

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Is it possible to set the time when uploading the program on the fgpa board?

Comment: No it's not possible but you can start to count time from 0 at the start of the FPGA.

Comment: I found another website where someone tries it with an RTC module (Real Time Clock). Take a look here: [link](http://jimmy-embedded-c-n-vhdl.blogspot.com/2010/09/synthesizable-rtc-in-vhdl-coming-soon.html)

I think it is possible to give the current time in the execution, but I don't know how to do that (at this moment). I would have to figure out that.

Comment: @Gautitho, I thought about that too. maybe you can make a clock with the current time through the internal clock.

Comment: @Joost  you mean, when fpga including rtc, i can upload my current time. right? 
sorry, my english skill is terrible :(

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Did you follow the link I had send to you? I saw another link. In this link it's possible to set time manualy [here](http://jimmy-embedded-c-n-vhdl.blogspot.com/2011/01/rtc-on-fpga-with-manual-set.html)

Answer (score 1):

In HDL you can only keep track of the elapsed time, using some counters running from an external reference: a clock signal with a known frequency.

You always have to set the current date/time by initializing<sup>1</sup> your counter registers. Setting the time/date is normally done through a CPU interface. Which implies you need a CPU which gets the time from somewhere (A real-time clock or a connection to the outside world) and then writes the time in some format to your registers.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Even if your FPGA has battery backup: it always has to be set at least the first time.</sub>